# xsl how do I apply a XML document as a variable to a template

Tags: xml, variables, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have this basic template which sorts & removes certain nodes from my XML document. It works as expected in a stand alone XSLT when passing the XML file as an input parameter of a Saxon command.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:sort select="RatingDate" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ChangesByServerID|Distance|NewRatingPending"/>
```

However, I want to include it in an existing XSL file where the XML file is loaded into a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="BANES_326" select="document('FHRS_BANES_326.xml')"/>
```

How do I pass the XML variable to this routine?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do `<xsl:apply-templates select="$BANES_236"/>`